# Excel: Copying rows to table in another sheet using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently working on a spreadsheet in Excel.

My aim is to create a VBA that copies rows with specific criteria to the next sheet in my workbook and to a "log sheet".

My VBA looks like this:

```
Sub ImportRows()

    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xCell As Range
    Dim I As Long
    Dim J As Long
    Dim K As Long
    I = Worksheets("Print").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    J = Worksheets("Store").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    If J = 1 Then
       If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Store").UsedRange) = 0 Then J = 0
    End If
    Set xRg = Worksheets("Print").Range("I2:I" & I)
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For K = 1 To xRg.Count
        If CStr(xRg(K).Value) = "Print" Then

            xRg(K).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Store").Range("A" & J +1) 
            xRg(K).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Log").Range("A" & J +1) 
            xRg(K).EntireRow.Delete
            If CStr(xRg(K).Value) = "Print" Then
                K = K - 1
            End If
            J = J + 1
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

The problem is when I am copying from Sheet1 called Print the data is in a table, but when I copy into the next sheet called "store" (or Log) - The data doesn't go into to table but appears in the first row beneath the table making it impossible to sort the data.

Any suggestions on how to fix this? I think, that it might have something to do with the destination range, but I'm not sure.

---

I'm also struggling with the amount of data that I'm copying - When copying from "Print" to "store" I only wish to copy cell "A:H" and not "EntireRow".

---

I'm fairly new to Excel! I appreciate any help!

Thank you!

---

I have uploaded a screenshot that shows what the "Store" looks like after I have run the macro.

[image]

http://imageshack.com/a/img922/9446/gpL9Ov.png

Comment: to copy range A:H, you can use `intersect(xRg(K).EntireRow, Range("A:H")).Copy ...`

Comment: i'm sorry i don't get you, is the 'store' / 'log' sheet has a list table in it, and the data does not goes into the table? List table i mean the one we insert through the INSERT menu followed by Table under the Tables group.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!

The "Print" sheet is a table, where I can sort on "Date" - When I copy the rows to the next sheet (Store), I would like to be able to sort on the date as well since I want those rows with the next due date to be on top. 

I Hope this makes it more clear

Comment: np... Is it possible to make a screen shot of how 'store' / 'log' sheet looks like after you ran the macro? so we can have better idea whats going on?

Comment: http://imageshack.com/a/img922/9446/gpL9Ov.png

Comment: I have uploaded a screenshot that shows what the "Store" looks like after I have run the macro. 

Thank you for your time

Comment: great! it looks like you have a list table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have a list object table, it would be much easier.

To copy from A:H columns of the row only, use `Intersect()` to crop for A:H column.

Then to copy into a list object table, set the destination to a new *list row*:

```
Intersect(xRg(K).EntireRow, Range("A:H")).Copy _
    Destination:=range("Table1").ListObject.ListRows.Add.Range
```

The table name can be found below, which is defaulted to Table#:

[image: Menu]

[image: table name]